# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML: Put Enum Value into XAML Attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, windows-phone-8.1

This is my Enum structure:

```
namespace MyNS
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        MyValOne = 1,
        MyValTwo = 2
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="1" />
<RadioButton x:Name="2" />
```

I want something like this: (The **x:Name** attribute is not important. Any attribute is ok)

```
<RadioButton x:Name="MyNS.MyEnum.MyValOne" />
<RadioButton x:Name="MyNS.MyEnum.MyValTwo" />
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what is your end goal? Are you looking to bind enums? You can't bind attribues, such as `x:Name`.

Comment: What about Tag attribute? I have RadioButtons of Enum Values. Then I use them in the code.

Comment: So you need to get your enum from selected radiobutton?

Comment: @RenDishen, Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need an enum converter like this.

```
public class EnumRadioButtonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value.ToString() == parameter.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), parameter.ToString(), true) : null;
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it (don't forget to give them a `GroupName`). You will need to define a `SelectedEnum` property (of type `MyEnum`) in your viewmodel of course.

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedEnum, ConverterParameter=MyValTwo, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="MyRadioButtonGroup" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedEnum, ConverterParameter=MyValOne, Converter={StaticResource EnumRadioButtonConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="MyRadioButtonGroup" />
```

To use the converter, you need to reference it in your resource section.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:EnumRadioButtonConverter x:Key="EnumRadioButtonConverter" />
```

Please find a working sample [here](http://1drv.ms/1xsx4AZ).

Comment: So How can I get the selected RadioButton value?

Comment: And I get **Resource EnumRadioButtonConverter is not found**. How can I reference the Class to my XAML?

Comment: See my updated answer. You will need to define a `SelectedEnum` property and bind the `IsChecked` to it. To use a converter, you will first need to reference it in xaml.

Comment: Could you please provide me an example of getting selected RadioButton value?

Comment: Sure, please see my updated answer. There's a working sample attached. :)

Comment: Thank you Justin. It really helps. But I'v thought that it could be simpler. Thanks any way.